# VSCode shortcut for move open editor up / down (not group but open editor)

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-code

I don't mean move editor group or viewed file (split editor groups); -- ***but in the list of open editors in the sidebar.***

They can be rearranged by mouse-dragging them into desired position. Can't find the name for shortcut command, if it exists.

For clarity, attaching a screenshot: (it's unfortunately way too large)

[image: screenshot of open editors from the sidebar]

Use case is rearranging open editors according to some flow (of data, functions or whatever) to simplify thinking about it.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think there are any exposed commands for that.

Comment: You do know that moving the tabs in the editor re-arranges the `open editors view` too?  So any commnad that moves the tabs, like `Move Editor Right/Left` will accomplish the same thing.

Comment: No I didn't know that since I don't use tabs. But yes, this is **exactly what I was looking for**. Thanks @Mark If you'd care, copy paste that as the answer. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see any command that would allow you to re-order the `Open Editors` list directly.

But the order of that list is determined by the order of your opened tabs, so if you move the file tabs around the `Open Editors` list changes to match.  So these would do what you want:

Move Editor Left:    <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PageUp</kbd>

Move Editor Right:  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>PageDown</kbd>

This works even if you have the setting `Editor: Show Tabs` disabled so that only a single tab is displayed - you can still move that tab left and right and that is reflected in the `Open Editors` list!!